# java database installation directory location & database location

Tags: database-connection

java database installation directory location & database location

I am trying to get my Java DB setup correctly with NetBeans 6.9.1 to start building databases.

When I right-click on Java DB every option is greyed out except for Properties. There is no sample databases or anything else

when selected, a popup appears requesting
Java DB Installation:
Database Location:
and an info line saying
Please enter the Java DB installation directory.

can anyone tell me where the installation directory (and driver associated with it) is located and how to get past this screen and begin database creation.

Answer (score 0):

Normally JavaDB should be installed as part of the JDK, in a subdirectory called db of the JDK installation directory.  However, I just noticed that the JDK6 I have here doesn't have this directory, but the JDK7 installation does. And Netbeans is using the JavaDB installation that came with a Glassifsh appserver I have as well...

You could look for a file called `ij` (the command line tool that comes with JavaDB, and apparently even on Windows system the shellscript call ij is installed) somewhere on your system, that name is unique enough to avoid false positives.

If you don't find any JavaDB installation, as you can point Netbeans to any Derby install you can find, you could install a fresh copy of Apache Derby, they're a number of versions ahead of the official JavaDB distribution.